# I have a program in c that doesn't work as it should with parity very well

Tags: c, parity

My code doesn't display matrices larger than n>1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_N 10

int n;
int matrix[MAX_N][MAX_N];
bool used[MAX_N * MAX_N + 1];
int count = 0;

bool check(int row, int col, int val) {
    if (row > 0 && abs(val - matrix[row-1][col]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with northern neighbor
    }
    if (col > 0 && abs(val - matrix[row][col-1]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with western neighbor
    }
    if (row < n-1 && abs(val - matrix[row+1][col]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with southern neighbor
    }
    if (col < n-1 && abs(val - matrix[row][col+1]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with eastern neighbor
    }
    return true; //all neighbors respect the parity condition
}

void print_matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void backtrack(int row, int col) {
    if (row == n) {
        count++;
        print_matrix();
        return;
    }
    if (col == n) {
        backtrack(row+1, 0);
        return;
    }
    for (int val = 1; val <= n*n; val++) {
        if (!used[val] && check(row, col, val)) {
            matrix[row][col] = val;
            used[val] = true;
            backtrack(row, col+1);
            used[val] = false;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter the size of the array n (maxim %d): ", MAX_N);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 0 || n > MAX_N) {
        printf("The array size is invalid.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("The matrices that respect the condition are:\n");
    backtrack(0, 0);
    printf("Total number of arrays generated: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to solve the problem with displaying matrices when n>1. Or if I did not complete the program correctly, you can help me. This is my task: Generate all nxn matrices containing distinct elements from the set {1,...,n^2}, so that no element in the matrix has the same parity as its neighbors (neighbors of an element are considered in N, S, E, W directions).

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're filling in the matrix from top-to-bottom, left-to-right.  But as you do, you're rejecting values that don't have odd parity *before* setting the values that follow it, which means you will reject values that would work if a later adjacent value were changed.  For example, when you encounter 2, 0, you will reject the 2, even though 2, 1 would work.  You should only check against values that have already been set.

Comment: @Dragos Andriuta, `abs(val - matrix[row-1][col]) % 2 == 0` fails when `val - matrix[row-1][col]` outside `int` range  (overflow).  It is also an incorrect parity check when the 2 values are odd and of different signs.  Better as `!(val%2) == !(matrix[row-1][col]%2)`.

Comment: Even better as `(val ^ matrix[row-1][col])&1 == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change `check` to only consider values that have been previously set.  This is very easy, since you can take advantage of the order in which they're set.  Just eliminate the last two cases, so you end up with:

```
bool check(int row, int col, int val) {
    if (row > 0 && abs(val - matrix[row-1][col]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with northern neighbor
    }
    if (col > 0 && abs(val - matrix[row][col-1]) % 2 == 0) {
        return false; // check parity with western neighbor
    }
    return true; //all neighbors respect the parity condition
}
```

This only checks the values above and to the left of the current value.

Note that it does *not* suffice to check for zero values, since that will fail after it backtracks (in which case subsequent values are not guaranteed to be zero).

Answer (score 1):

The code checks the values in the matrix *while* it's beeing constructed, so that some of the neighbors are still 0. You may change the conditions in `check` like the following:

```
if (     row > 0  
     &&  matrix[row-1][col] != 0
     && (val - matrix[row-1][col]) % 2 == 0 ) {
    return false; // check parity with northern neighbor
}
```

Note, though, that you could exploit the fact that only matrices with a pattern of alternating odd and even values are possible solutions.

Comment: This doesn't work.  After backtracking, subsequent values will not all be zero.  E.g. You do 1, 0, then 1, 2, then it backtracks and tries 2, 2 which will be rejected, even though 2, 1 works.

Comment: @TomKarzes after backtrack they just need to reset the value, as they already  do with `used`, but your solution is more efficient.

Comment: Agreed, that would fix the problem.